# Saving an IAP receipt

Tags: cocoa, in-app-purchase, storekit

I would like to save in IAP receipt for non-consumables in my database. We have a two-step download mechanism for IAP restores.

1. Retrieve all transactions with the StoreKit mechanism which include the receipt.
2. Choose the transaction to restore at a later point in time from a list of all receipts (i.e. the products behind those receipts)

Is there any word regarding on how long the data can be treated as valid? What other drawbacks could I encounter by persisting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a date when your receipt invalidates—you can always send it to Apple server and it will decode it to JSON for you.

At least, there is no such info anyway, so untill Apple will do such a thing in one way order, you can feel safe to store it.